# JSONP with Sencha Touch not working

Tags: php, json, sencha-touch

I was following this tutorial of Sencha Touch: http://www.vimeo.com/15672696
Perfect tutorial, worked flawless.

But when I tried to reuse this code for my own project, I doesn't work.
Here is wat I did:

In my Sencha touch application I wrote the following function:

```
showContacts = function()
{
    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: 'http://www.hotcoffee.be/check-relations/index.php/json/contactpersonen',
        callbackKey: "callback",
        params: {
            unique: Math.random()
        },
        callback: function(data)
        {
            var contacts = data.results;
            nameOfPanel.update(contacts);
        }
    });
}
```

First, I wrote my own JSON file with PHP (codeigniter):

```
<?
    $row[] = array(
        "name" => $item->name,
        "first_name" => $item->first_name,
        "avatar"=>$item->avatar
    );

    // PASSING THE ARRAY $row TO A VIEW
    // ON THE VIEW I OUTPUT THE ARRAY

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row));
?>
```

(Result: see URL of showContacts function)

This didn't work, so I assumed something was wrong with using a PHP file as JSON, so I created a JSON file:

(Result: http://www.hotcoffee.be/check-relations/json/friends.json)

Now it seems that also this didn't work. I'm breaking my head over it a lot of houres...
I also receive the following messages in Chrome's debugger:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json. (contactpersonen:-1)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (contactpersonen:1)
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html. (csi:-1)
```

Another thing is that I can ensure that the panels and tpl's are written well, because with hardcoded testdata it does work. Only loading the JSON file is the problem.

Anyone knows how to handle it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: JSONP works by wrapping JSON in a callback function (so that it can be included with a <script> tag and work across different origin domains). You're only returning raw JSON here. If it's on the same domain, you can just use JSON. Is the app on the same domain as the JSON source?

Comment: Well, now the JSON file is on the same domain, but in the future I would like to fetch it from another host. So I guess I want to let it work from another domain from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [Sencha seems to not like Rails' json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666828/sencha-seams-to-not-like-rails-json/5667416#5667416). It is specific to Rails but the concept still applies.

Essentially James Pearce is correct.  What you are returning needs to be wrapped in a  tag and the callback function.  This will insert the code on your page and run the script, which has the effect of calling the function you provide.

```
$response = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
$response .= $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($row) . ")";
$response .= "</script>";
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output($response);
```

Comment: Thnx James Pearce & mistagrooves! Both are correct, I found the solution with James Pearce's info.

Comment: FWIW, for some reason this only works for me if I remove `<script type='text/javascript'>` and `</script>` -- ie, do not use the 1st and 3rd lines above

Answer (score 3):

this is the example of php server:

```
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];

// Create the output object.
$output = array('a' => 'Apple', 'b' => 'Banana');

//start output
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

while you debug it in chrome or firefox,you can find that the response was joined with `Ext.util.JSONP.callback({})`

that is how jsonp "retrieving data from a page that is in a domain that is NOT the same as the originating domain of the running page" ,and give the data to your running page.