# Sencha touch with rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sencha-touch-2

I have a rails app and now I'd like to provide a mobile UI so now I'm evaluating Sencha Touch. 
My goal is to create Sencha Touch views and serve them through the rails not roller through js format. However I have hard ime to make it work or find any sample. So, I'm wondering if it is even possible to achieve so.

Anyone knows how o achieve so?

Thanks and have a good one.

Comment: http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1/

Comment: so, it looks like it is impossible to achieve my goal. THX

Comment: Its definately possible, maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666828/sencha-seems-to-not-like-rails-json

Comment: Thanks Jeffery, I will try to apply what I found in the post you pointed to.