# sencha touch rest proxy url

Tags: rest, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Why if a use a JSON file foo.json my code works but if I change the URL to something.com/foo.json it doesn´t work?

This is working in my project:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Client',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'clients.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want is to replace the static file for an URL:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Client',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'http://rails-api.herokuapp.com/clients.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    });
```

The clients.json file is a copy/paste from http://rails-api.herokuapp.com/clients.json it is the same data.

Comment: You should read carefully the doc.  The server that you made request should respond `callback` by `jsonp` type. If url that you request on your domain, does not necessary to use `jsonp`. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: yes, but the webservice is intended to be public so I needed to add the callback :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side I had to add the callback, see this question [sencha-seems-to-not-like-rails-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666828/sencha-seems-to-not-like-rails-json) also I had to change the type from rest to [jsonp](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/#!/api/Ext.util.JSONP) and removed some useless code, at the end my code looks like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Client',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url : 'http://rails-api.herokuapp.com/clients.json'
        }
    });
```

on the server side:

```
def index
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json { render :json => @clients, :callback => params[:callback] }
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you run your application? Are you able to track the http requests? Do you get any output on your javascript console?

If i had to guess I'd say that your issue might be related to CORS => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

**Edit:**
Note that you only need to have a look at CORS or use jsonp if you are running your app and the "backend"/api on two different webservers.

Most people will probably...

- a) ...run the app on the same webserver as the backend or...
- b) ...use native packaging (cordova, phonegap or sencha cmd s own packaging).

In both cases you can simply use the "normal" ajax or rest proxys.

Comment: I'm new into sencha... for now I'm running the code in a apache tomcat instaled on my PC. I'll take a look at CORS, I'll let you know, thanks for now

Comment: it works now, telling me about CORS was really helpful @Adrian but still it doesn't solve the whole issue unless I change the type to jsonp instead of rest.